# How to add image in SharePoint online list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

In SP on-premise, we could add a content editor web part and add an image in the new form.

I need to do the same thing with SharePoint online, and I am unsure how to do it.

So basically, what I need to do is every time users want to create a new list (form), they should see an image on top of the page.

Comment: Hi @Harris, is my below solution working for you? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint Online modern experience, you can add an image to the list form by applying JSON formatting to the Header section like this:

```
{
    "elmType": "img",
    "style": {
        "width": "100%",
        "max-width": "100%",
        "float": "left"
    },
    "attributes": {
        "src": "=@currentWeb + '/SiteAssets/Microsoft products banner.jpg'"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**:

[Configure the list form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration)

**Examples:**

The following examples may assist in understanding how the formatting behaves in the header.

*Example 01*

Without adding `display: block` to the parent, the parent will have `flex` applied, children will display inline.

```json
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "children":
    [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Line 01.\n\n"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Line 02.\n\n"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "img",
            "attributes":
            {
                "src": "https://picsum.photos/600/300"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

will produce:

[image]

*Example 02*

When adding `display: block` to the parent, the parent will not have `flex` applied, children will display as blocks.

```json
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "style":
    {
        "display": "block"
    },
    "children":
    [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Line 01.\n\n"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Line 02.\n\n"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "img",
            "attributes":
            {
                "src": "https://picsum.photos/600/300"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

will produce:

[image]

*Example 03*

If you want to modify [the sample header that is provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-header) so that is has some text and an image below it, you could try something like this:

```json
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "style":
    {
        "display": "block",
        "width": "99%",
        "border-top-width": "0px",
        "border-bottom-width": "1px",
        "border-left-width": "0px",
        "border-right-width": "0px",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "margin-bottom": "16px",
        "padding-bottom": "20px"
    },
    "children":
    [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes":
            {
                "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralTertiary"
            },
            "style":
            {
                "display": "flex"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style":
                    {
                        "display": "flex",
                        "box-sizing": "border-box",
                        "align-items": "center"
                    },
                    "children":
                    [
                        {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "attributes":
                            {
                                "iconName": "EditContact",
                                "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
                                "title": "Details"
                            },
                            "style":
                            {
                                "flex": "none",
                                "padding": "0px",
                                "padding-left": "0px",
                                "height": "36px"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes":
                    {
                        "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
                    },
                    "style":
                    {
                        "box-sizing": "border-box",
                        "width": "100%",
                        "text-align": "left",
                        "padding": "21px 12px",
                        "overflow": "hidden"
                    },
                    "children":
                    [
                        {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "txtContent": "My Header Title"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Line 01.\n\n"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Line 02.\n\n"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "img",
            "attributes":
            {
                "src": "https://picsum.photos/600/300"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: That was useful. I didn't knew about this .Thanks for Sharing

Comment: You're welcome @Saira!

Comment: Hi @Harris, did you try this? Is it working for you? let me know if you have any further doubt in this.

Comment: It's a pity the [example header layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-header) uses relatively complex nested divs and child divs using `flex` styling.  I'd like to add image and text divs _beneath_ the header icon and text, but can't figure out how to put them on a 'new line'.  Am having a 'peter griffin CSS meme' moment.

Comment: I investigated my query further, and made some additions to the answer, to demonstrate how the formatting behaves in regards to flex etc.